# Evaluate socket.recv() all the time

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, raspberry-pi

I have a client script running on a Raspberry Pi 3. The client is receiving from a server whether it is TRUE or FALSE. After this it receives a bytes-like object which it decodes and uses this information to show an image in a GUI.

It checks if the GPIO pin gets TRUE from a button press, and loops back to the first .recv().

I want the client to check all the time if it gets the message "new game", and if so go to the first .recv() where it checks if it is TRUE or FALSE.

But since my .recv() function blocks I can't do anything while stuck there.

How can I check if I receive information while still checking if the GPIO state changes to TRUE.

The code looks like this:

```
#imports needed
import socket
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import tkinter as tk
import pygame

#Setup of GPIO pin for buttons used as bumpers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(36, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Pin 36 = GPIO16


#Setup of root window for the GUI and the different images 
root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

image6 = tk.PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/Desktop/wav/wrong.gif")
wronglabel = tk.Label(image=image6)

image5 = tk.PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/Desktop/wav/correct.gif")
correctlabel = tk.Label(image=image5)

image4 = tk.PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/Desktop/wav/questionmark.gif")
questionlabel = tk.Label(image=image4)

pygame.init()

#Setup of the different sounds to use in the project
correctsound = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/Desktop/wav/correct.wav')
wrongsound = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/Desktop/wav/wrong.wav')

HOST = '192.168.1.34'    # The remote host, 
PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try: 
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))

except:
    print("FAILED. Sleep briefly & try again")
    time.sleep(10)
    continue

questionlabel.pack()
root.update()
while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data == b'True':
        print('I am the true cone')
        state = True        
    if data == b'False':
        print('I am the false cone')
        state = False


    byte_string = s.recv(1024)
    path = '/home/pi/Desktop/wav/%s.gif' % byte_string.decode()
    questionlabel.pack_forget()

    image1 = tk.PhotoImage(file=path) #x should change accordingly to the received message 
    Thelabel = tk.Label(image=image1)
    Thelabel.pack()
    root.update()

    i=0
    while i==0:
        if GPIO.input(36) == True:
            if state == True:
                Thelabel.pack_forget()
                correctlabel.pack()
                root.update()
                correctsound.play()
                s.sendall(b'True Hit')
                time.sleep(5)
                correctlabel.pack_forget()
                questionlabel.pack()
                root.update()

            if state == False:
                Thelabel.pack_forget()
                wronglabel.pack()
                root.update()
                wrongsound.play()
                time.sleep(5)
                wronglabel.pack_forget()
                questionlabel.pack()
                root.update()
            i=1
```

Comment: You are asking about asynchronous i/o, and there are many ways of handling it. Possible solutions involve using `select.poll`, using threads, or looking into the `asynchio` module (among others!). Note that `Rpi.GPIO` also implements an asynchronous callback-based interrupt mechanism that may allow you to implement a solution while still having a blocking call to `recv`.  Maybe take some time to investigate the various options.

Comment: wow, so many things are wrong here, don't know where to start :/ But in any case, you need another thread to check your client/server

Comment: @dgan Fell free to come with suggestions for changes or critique. Than you would make this thread restart the other when receiving the correct message?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's quite difficult to understand what you tried here, you have only global variables, imperative code style, and everything is interleaved... I am struggling to get exactly what you need.

There is no chance that my code will solve your problem out-of-the-box, but I hope it will help you to understand where to dig to solve your problem:

```
# imports needed
import socket
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from threading import Thread

try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

import pygame

# Setup of GPIO pin for buttons used as bumpers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(36, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # Pin 36 = GPIO16


class MyTk():
"""All tkinter stuff goes here"""

    def __init__(self, pygame_app):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.pygame_app = pygame_app
        self.pygame_app.init()
        self.root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

        image6 = PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/Desktop/wav/wrong.gif")
        self.wronglabel = Label(image=image6, master=self.root)  # ? unused

        image5 = PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/Desktop/wav/correct.gif")
        self.correctlabel = Label(image=image5, master=self.root)  # ? unused

        image4 = PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/Desktop/wav/questionmark.gif")
        self.questionlabel = Label(image=image4, master=self.root)

        self.questionlabel.pack()
        self.root.update()

    def update_for_right(self):
        correctsound = self.pygame_app.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/Desktop/wav/correct.wav')
        self._forget_TheLabel()
        correctsound.play()
        time.sleep(5)
        self._forget_correct()

    def _set_TheLabel(self, path):
        image1 = PhotoImage(file=path)  # x should change accordingly to the received message
        self.Thelabel = Label(image=image1, master=self.root)
        self.Thelabel.pack()
        self.root.update()

    def update_for_wrong(self):
        # Setup of the different sounds to use in the project
        wrongsound = self.pygame_app.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/Desktop/wav/wrong.wav')
        wrongsound.play()
        time.sleep(5)
        self._forget_wrong()

    def _forget_wrong(self):
    """you should not call underscored methods from outside of   this class"""
        self.wronglabel.forget()
        self.root.update()

    def _forget_correct(self):
        self.correctlabel.pack_forget()
        self.questionlabel.pack()
        self.root.update()

    def _forget_TheLabel(self):
        self.Thelabel.pack_forget()
        self.root.update()

    def _forget_question_label(self):
        self.questionlabel.pack_forget()
        self.root.update()


class MySocket():
"""All socket stuff goes here"""
    def __init__(self, tkinter_app, host='192.168.1.34', port=5007):
    """This class needs a dependency(tkinter), so pass it as constructor argument, and use it later"""

        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.tkinter_app = tkinter_app

    def try_connect(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        while 1:
            try:
                self.s.connect((self.host, self.port))
                return
            except:
                print("FAILED. Sleep briefly & try again")
                time.sleep(10)

    def listen(self):
        """This blocks execution until something is received"""
        while True:
            data = self.s.recv(1024)
            if data == b'True':
                byte_string = self.s.recv(1024)  # antoher signal is sent?
                print('I am the true cone')
                state = True
                self.do_stuff(state, data)
            else:
                # this is useles...
                print('I am the false cone')
                state = False

    def do_stuff(self, state, data):
        path = '/home/pi/Desktop/wav/%s.gif' % data.decode()
        self.tkinter_app._set_TheLabel(path)
        if GPIO.input(36) == True:
            if state:
                self.s.sendall(b'True Hit')
                self.tkinter_app.update_for_right()

            else:
                self.s.sendall(b'False Hit')  # ?
                self.tkinter_app.update_for_wrong()

        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mytk = MyTk(pygame)
    mysk = MySocket(mytk)
    mysk.try_connect()
    # this call blocks; so you need at least another thread to run your Tkinter
    th = Thread(target=mytk.root.mainloop)  # launch tkinter GUI
    th.start()
    # this block the main thread
    mysk.listen()
```